# how to use numpy plus each rows in a martix with every rows in another martix

Tags: python, numpy

Here is the example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2],[3,4],[5,6])
b = np.array([7,8],[9,10],[11,12],[12,13])
```

what I want is to use each item in a to plus every item in b then plus them together. For example, [1,2] should plus every row in b 1+7=8,2+8=10, 8+10=18;1+9=10,2+10=12,10+12=22... The result would like to be that`[[18,22,26,28...],[22,26,....],[26,30....]]`
My question is how to fulfil that? I know use numpy can be more efficient than loop but how to use the matrix to calculate this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
>>> b = np.array([[7,8],[9,10],[11,12],[12,13]])
>>> np.sum(a, axis=1)[:,None] + np.sum(b, axis=1)[None,:]
array([[18, 22, 26, 28],
       [22, 26, 30, 32],
       [26, 30, 34, 36]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
b = np.array([[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12], [12, 13]])

[[sum(i) + sum(j) for j in b] for i in a]
```

Output:

```
[[18, 22, 26, 28], [22, 26, 30, 32], [26, 30, 34, 36]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the most precise and succinct way as follows:

```
np.einsum('ijk-> ij', a[:,None,:]+b)
```

Let me explain each step.It combines einsum and broadcasting concepts of numpy.

Step 1- `a[:,None,:]` reshapes matrix `a` to shape (3,1,2). This mid axis with value 1 is helpful for broadcasting.

Step 2- `a[:,None,:] + b` broadcasts `a` and adds matrix `b` to get a resultant matrix of shape (3,4,2).

Step 3- `np.einsum('ijk-> ij', a[:,None,:]+b)` does sum reduction along the last axis of matrix obtained from previous step.